# Pandas - selecting rows from data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Hi all I'm new to pandas, I have a dataframe with several rows for given index or id in this case.  I would like to subset this data frame so that for each id i will only get rows up to the first time column A and C are zero and discard rest of the rows with all zeros.

```
id                            A             B          C            
10000                     728185.14       1000000    728185.14
10000                     578311.73       1000000    578311.73
10000                     496633.66       1000000    496633.66
10000                     367326.97       1000000    367326.97
10000                          0.00       1000000         0.00
10000                          0.00             0         0.00
10000                          0.00             0         0.00
10000                          0.00             0         0.00
10000                          0.00             0         0.00
```

here is what it should look like after i subset the dataframe

```
id                            A             B          C            
10000                     728185.14       1000000    728185.14
10000                     578311.73       1000000    578311.73
10000                     496633.66       1000000    496633.66
10000                     367326.97       1000000    367326.97
10000                          0.00       1000000         0.00
```

Andy ides?

I also have one other question, how can i select last row for each index? So after I do the step above I would like to create a new data frame with a last row for each index.

```
id                         A            B       C           
10000                     0.00      1000000    0.00
10001                     0.00      1000000    0.00
10002                     0.00      1000000    0.00
10003                     0.00      1000000    0.00
10004                     0.00      1000000    0.00
```

Comment: Perhaps there's something more to your data than this, but why not just `df.query('B != 0')`?

Comment: A simple method would be `df.loc[:((df['A'] == 0) & (df['C'] == 0)).idxmax()]` but this doesn't apply for every id

Comment: in the example above that will work. But for some index B is not zero at the first instance A and C go to zero and the df.query('B != 0') will not work but i would still like to get all the rows up to when A and C goes to zero first time and disregard other rows with zeros.

Comment: I think my answer in my comment would work but not for every id

Comment: @EdChum you can just groupby id then apply idxmax (filter before the groupby)

Comment: You should post additional questions as a separate post to stop this being a thread

Comment: @Jeff just tried the following: `df.loc[:((df['A'] == 0) & (df['C'] == 0)).idxmax()].groupby('id')` doesn't quite capture the OP's requirement, have I understood your suggestion incorrectly, also I've not forgotten about contributing to the docs, I can't believe how much of a pain in the ar$e it was to compile the source code on windows, in the end it was much much easier using WinPython rather than anaconda as the environment

Comment: I mean ``df.loc[.....].groupby('id').idxmax()``